# How do I disable font smoothing/hinting/anti-aliasing on Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, anti-aliasing

Full disclosure: I'm predominantly a Chrome user on Windows, but I finally let Firefox download and install the latest version, 4.0. Considering this version has been in development forever, I frankly expected better.

It appears that they've "improved" text rendering by applying font smoothing or anti-aliasing across the entire user interface—not just the text displayed on the pages themselves, but also the text in menus, toolbars, and dialog boxes. Even the context menus use a re-hinted version of Segoe UI.

I think it's blurry and very difficult to read. **How do I turn it off?** I can't find anything in the Options dialog that looks useful. Perhaps it's something in `about:config`, but I don't know enough about Firefox to know where to start looking. I can't imagine they would make such a dramatic change without providing the facility to revert to the classic rendering mode if the user so desired. Open source software is notorious for gratuitous customizability; here's a case where I would actually appreciate it.

Additionally, I've discovered that I frequently out-run its ability to process input. In every text entry field that I've come across, I've out-typed Firefox's ability to display each character. More than once, I've even managed to crash the browser trying to type, with only one tab loaded. I *suspect* this is related to the font rendering changes, as anti-aliasing requires more computing "umph". I'm hoping that if I find the button to turn that off, it'll fix the **severe typing lag**. But if anyone just so happens to have any *other* suggestions on how I might fix that, I'm all ears.

The machine in question is a Dual Xeon with 5 GB of RAM running Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Find the item labeled `gfx.direct2d.disabled`, and change its value to `True`.

This turns off hardware acceleration and should make your fonts more readable.

Comment: Excellent, that helped a lot. (Although it's still significantly slower than Chrome, and I still see some typing lag.) Also, is this the same thing as the "Use hardware acceleration when available" checkbox under the "Advanced" tab in the Options dialog?

Comment: I believe so. There is a rather interesting thread about this over at Mozillazine: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2060933.

Comment: Hmm yeah, it looks like it is. And I read as much of that discussion as I could stand. It's just a bunch of uninformed people ranting and theorizing. There's no official word from any of the devs (but a lot of reasons why I prefer SE to traditional forums). If this is what fonts are going to look like now on Windows, I'm going to have to give it up completely for the Mac. I can't use WPF applications like Expression Blend for the same reason—the fonts look like crap. It's just not that hard to get font rendering right; not sure why MS has so much trouble. Nor why Mozilla has adopted it...

Comment: Thank you very much. It now works perfectly with MacType and now I can see pretty customized font rendered text instead of ugly ClearType. Despite the question is about Firefox 4, it works for Firefox 16 as well. So thanks again!

Comment: I didn't see this option under Firefox 36.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In more recent Firefox (38+) and SeaMonkey (2.35+) versions, `gfx.direct2d.disabled` has nothing to do with HW acceleration with regard to fonts display. Instead, you may need to set `layers.acceleration.disabled=true`.

Additionally, it may be your graphics card driver settings which cause your fonts to look anti-aliased. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1064589) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Since Firefox 60, the setting to disable anti-aliasing is now  `gfx.text.disable-aa`.

Comment: This question was from a version of Firefox from 2011.  Firefox 4 and Firefox 60 are substantially different.  This answer sadly isn’t accurate for Firefox 4