# How to disable font smoothing on Firefox 18 for Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, fonts

On my Ubuntu 12.10 machine, I've updated Firefox to version 18 some minutes ago. After that, fonts on sites are too smooth and now it's difficult to read for me.

I found some advices about my problem like that question [How do I disable font smoothing/hinting/anti-aliasing on Firefox 4?](https://superuser.com/questions/267726/how-do-i-disable-font-smoothing-hinting-anti-aliasing-on-firefox-4) and read official forums but on my machine there are none of the following items in `about:config`:

- `gfx.direct2d.disabled`
- `gfx.content.azure.enabled`

And the addon [Anti-Aliasing Tuner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/) is not available for me either.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Try manually creating the values by going to about:config and right-clicking anywhere blank: New -> Boolean. Make sure you get the spelling correct. Also, try disabling hardware acceleration (Options -> Advanced -> Untick use hardware acceleration when available). Make sure you restart the browser after every change you make to let the changes set in.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a boolean setting `gfx.direct2d.disabled` in `about:config`
- Set its value to  `True`

The above worked for me.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work for text on transparent background, at least in some cases. When the background is visually, say, white but in fact transparent, the text is blurred; when a colour is assigned —be it white or any(?) other— the text has default system-wide anti-aliasing. This didn't happen until Firefox was upgraded from v.17 to 18.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Creating ~/.fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="autohint" >
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the following preferences on the about:config page

layers.acceleration.force-enabled > true

layers.acceleration.disabled > false

gfx.xrender.enabled > false (this one "may", not sure yet, decrease performance a little but it will give you crisp & clean font rendering)

Comment: You won't believe me but these approaches don't give any effect.