# Turn off font smoothing in SeaMonkey for Windows

Tags: firefox, anti-aliasing, cleartype, seamonkey, font-smoothing

I'm running SeaMonkey on Windows 8.1, and I have recently upgraded to version **2.40**.

Although I have *full-pixel AA* and *ClearType* disabled entirely (which can be seen either by running **systempropertiesadvanced.exe**/**cttune.exe** or looking at simple MFC apps appearance), *SeaMonkey* still anti-aliases fonts -- both in the web pages and in its UI.

I've already seen [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/267726) for Firefox 4, so I made the following changes to my `prefs.js`:

- Set `gfx.direct2d.disabled` to `true`
- Set [`gfx.use_text_smoothing_setting`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gfx.use_text_smoothing_setting) to `true` (yes I'm aware it's *Mac OS X*-specific, but I gave it a try anyway)
- Set `gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.enabled` to `false` (this property was last available in 2.39 and is gone in 2.40, so I assume it may be no longer effective -- but I added it just in case).

No luck so far.

Then I downloaded [Anti-Aliasing Tuner](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/anti-aliasing-tuner/) add-on, [made it compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SeaMonkey_2) with SeaMonkey (for some reason, Firefox 43 personality in the `User Agent` string wasn't enough), installed it and set font rendering to "Aliased" wherever appropriate:

[image]

This resulted in the following extra preferences set:

```
extensions.aatuner.large.aamode = 3
extensions.aatuner.small.aamode = 3
extensions.aatuner.large.rdmode = 1
extensions.aatuner.small.rdmode = 1
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode = 1
```

(it looks `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode` just takes the same value as `extensions.aatuner.*.rdmode`).

Despite the above efforts, `SeaMonkey` still renders my fonts antialiased (and yes, I've restarted the browser multiple times).

How the heck do I turn AA off?

**Update #1:** for SeaMonkey 2.40 running on Windows XP, the same combination of settings gives perfect crisp aliased fonts (full-pixel AA and ClearType are disabled system-wide).

**Update #2:** SeaMonkey essentially uses **full-pixel AA** (meaning *ClearType* is off) -- see the screenshot below. Now, the only browsers that still can display aliased text on my Windows box are *Opera* and *Safari*.

[image: Full-pixel AA in SeaMonkey]

**Update #3:** starting SeaMonkey in safe mode **does** turn AA off. This is equivalent to un-checking "Use hardware acceleration when available" under Preferences -> Appearance -> Content. Clearing this flag actually sets both `gfx.direct2d.disabled` and `layers.acceleration.disabled` to `true`, while for aliased fonts display `layers.acceleration.disabled=true` alone is sufficient (and, as mentioned above, `gfx.direct2d.disabled` has no effect at all). Still, I would like some explicit preference for font display control, without the need to turn HW acceleration entirely.

**Update #4:** playing with *Anti-Aliasing Tuner* parameters only makes sense if at least full-pixel font smoothing (systempropertiesadvanced.exe -> Advanced -> Performance -> Visual Effects -> Smooth edges of screen fonts) is turned on in Windows. In this case, *ClearType* and *Greyscale* modes yield more blurred text than the *Aliased* mode (which can be called "almost aliased").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It were my *Intel HD Graphics* driver settings to be blamed. When "Application Optimal Mode" is on and "Conservative Morphological Anti-Aliasing" is set to either Override or Enhance Application Settings:

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel]

-- then fonts are always AA-ed in SeaMonkey if HW acceleration is on, regardless of font-specific settings. Intel driver-specific settings may even cause visual glitches with fonts display:

[image: SeaMonkey Visual Glitches]

This is a known Mozilla issue -- see [bug #1145987](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145987).